# Inverse record of a belongs_to record from a registration form not saving attributes

Tags: devise, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a registration form that asks for four things: the user's email, the user's name, their company's name, and a password.

The user model contains the email, name, and password fields

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :account
  attr_accessor :account_attributes
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :account


  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

end
```

The account model contains the company's name.

```
class Account < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :users,
           :dependent => :destroy

  attr_accessor :name

  validates :name, presence: true
end
```

My registration form looks like (using slim templates):

```
h2
  | Sign up
= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f|
  = devise_error_messages!
  .field
    = f.label :email
    br
    = f.email_field :email, autofocus: true
  .field
    = f.label :name, "Your name"
    br
    = f.text_field :name
  = f.fields_for :account_attributes do |a|
    .field
      = a.label :name, "Your company or organization"
      br
      = a.text_field :name
  .field
    = f.label :password
    - if @minimum_password_length
      em
        | (
        = @minimum_password_length
        |  characters minimum)
    br
    = f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off"
  .field
    = f.label :password_confirmation
    br
    = f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off"
  .actions
    = f.submit "Sign up"
= render "devise/shared/links"
```

And lastly, my custom registration controller is:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def new
    super
    resource.build_account
  end

  def create
    super
    resource.account ||= Account.new
    resource.account.name = sign_up_params[:account_attributes]["name"]
    resource.account.save
  end

  private

  def sign_up_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :account_attributes => [:name])
  end
end
```

The account relation itself persists, but the account NAME does not persist. Looking at the server logs, I can see where the account is persisted but I do not see the name persisting. The strange thing is I can see in the server where it attempts to do the transaction but ultimately doesn't issue any SQL update statement (and doesn't issue a rollback indicating there is no validation error).

```
  SQL (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO "accounts" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?)  [["created_at", 2016-10-27 16:39:33 UTC], ["updated_at", 2016-10-27 16:39:33 UTC]]
  SQL (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("name", "account_id", "created_at", "updated_at", "email", "encrypted_password") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["name", "dsfdsfds"], ["account_id", 32], ["created_at", 2016-10-27 16:39:33 UTC], ["updated_at", 2016-10-27 16:39:33 UTC], ["email", "dsfsdfsdf@fdsfasdfdsfsdfdsc.com"], ["encrypted_password", "$2a$11$pUhS5LGJO2VjPvlPVwj0KO6Ce5Ysr8s4Cu.R4kmsWe7CEayk7t8Fm"]]
   (2.2ms)  commit transaction
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
   (0.0ms)  commit transaction
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.3ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "updated_at" = ?, "sign_in_count" = ?, "current_sign_in_at" = ?, "last_sign_in_at" = ?, "current_sign_in_ip" = ?, "last_sign_in_ip" = ? WHERE "users"."id" = ?  [["updated_at", 2016-10-27 16:39:33 UTC], ["sign_in_count", 1], ["current_sign_in_at", 2016-10-27 16:39:33 UTC], ["last_sign_in_at", 2016-10-27 16:39:33 UTC], ["current_sign_in_ip", "::1"], ["last_sign_in_ip", "::1"], ["id", 36]]
   (0.5ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/products
```

I'm tearing my hair out and I've researched every SO question I could find that's seemingly related. I can do `puts sign_up_params[:account_attributes]["name"]` in the controller and the name I enter into the form prints back properly, I just can't seem to assign it to the model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `attr_accessor` on the account model is what caused this. By defining an attr_accessor, I was overriding Rails built in attribute accessors for database columns.

Simply removing `attr_accessor :name` from the Account model fixed this.